# What hidden features have you found in iOS 6?

Tags: ios

This is the required hidden gems questions for iOS 6.

Here are the rules:

- **One** feature per answer
- Also include **how** you use the feature or **why** it is useful
- Must be an under-documented feature. No "flag pole" features like VIP's in Mail.

Comment: I have made this CW and let's see how the community reacts to this. Not only are CW surveys not required - they work best when people can collaborate on one useful answer as opposed to a beauty contest where certain things get voted up or down for criteria that are vague at best. (e.g. "flag pole" to me certainly isn't the same to you. The whole idea of "under-documented" is so relative and a moment in time as Apple writes KB articles and all the details come out here, in reviews, and in training as people explore the OS.)

Comment: On devices with a magnetometer, tapping the location button in Maps a second time will make the view rotate with your device. (Posting this here for whoever starts following bmike's suggestion to use)

Comment: "Required" question. lol

Comment: The title and rules of this confuse me. As in, should they be outright hidden (something not documented on apple.com/ios ), or just not major? I love these questions, but usually end up being copies from the documentation.

Comment: Rather than add a bunch of answers - here is one of many good articles written to survey the _little things_ in iOS 6. [iOS 6 Features I Didn’t Know About](http://blog.chadwickwill.com/post/31894540460/ios-6-features-i-didnt-know-about) by [Chad Williams](https://twitter.com/supergoodnet)

Comment: @ughoavgfhw That's not a new feature in iOS 6.

Comment: I am pretty sure that all the new features are documented and therefore not hidden, some are just more apparent then others...

Comment: +33 Question score, WTF.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Searching for an app in Spotlight reveals **which folder** the app is located in.

Comment: Not all the time; I've had hit-or-miss luck with this, sometimes it just shows "Top Hit" for search queries.

Comment: @Veil If it's a top hit, it should be listed below with the folder too.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Just confirmed with a few different app searches, and it doesn't always happen, but when it does, it only shows as a "Top Hit", but nothing else.

Comment: hmm, I can't get it _not_ to work... also, very cool feature.  There were many times I'd 'lost' an app on the phone.  I could search for and find it, but I still didn't know where it was.

Answer (score 35):

**Alarms** can now make use of songs not just built in tones. Edit your alarm and select sound and then pick a song.

Comment: The only problem I find with this new feature is there's no way to disable the vibrations for alarms if they're enabled is settings. I'd prefer my phone to start playing the tune and not jump around on my nightstand while still vibrate when a message arrives or another alert is displayed.

Answer (score 33):

Tap and hold the "New Message" button inside Mail to open the Drafts folder.

Comment: Excellent little feature.

Comment: IIRC this was available in iOS 5 or earlier.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in 5.1.1

Comment: In iOS < 6, this used to bring back just the most recent saved draft.  This is much better.

Answer (score 32):

Receiving **iMessages** sent to your **phone number** on multiple devices.

I know this has been raved about but it is tricky to configure and took me a while to figure out.

Steps to get this working:

1. Disable and then re-enable iMessage on your phone (this triggers the registration process with Apple servers). Done in Settings -> Messages
2. Open Messages in Settings on other iOS devices and disable and then re-enable. This will add your phone number to the list. You need to then select it (a tick mark appears next to it). You will now receive messages on this device. There is also a section to choose to send from an address or number lower on the screen.
3. On OS X devices (10.8.2), open Messages and choose Preferences (from Messages menu) and then choose Accounts. You will now see your number and can select to receive messages on that device.

When you do this, you will get notifications on the other devices confirming that is enabled.

Comment: If I have other iOS 5 device (iPad 1), will it get iMessage that is sent to my phone number?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo That's a negative. Being able to consolidate messages received to a phone number is a new feature specific to iOS 6.

Comment: Does this include regular SMS messages as well as iMessages?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier No, unfortunately only iMessages

Comment: @Alain, ok thx.

Comment: I'm not sure why I see so many people saying that it's tricky to get this new iMessage functionality working. I upgraded my equipment to iOS 6 and upon the first boot I was prompted to use my phone number as my primary iMessage identifier on all my devices, including iPad. There were no extra steps.

Comment: @Phong, it depends how soon you adopted the new iOS. If you got in the first few hours, it was not totally slick. It has definitely improved but this is some steps people can take if they have problems.

Comment: @AlainKing I got it as soon as it was available for download.

Answer (score 32):

[iOS 6 Features I Didn’t Know About by Chad Williams](http://blog.chadwickwill.com/post/31894540460/ios-6-features-i-didnt-know-about) via [bmike♦](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64468/what-hidden-features-have-you-found-in-ios-6/64809#comment75964_64468)

> Metallic sliders across the OS now have a subtle reflection effect
>   that is created with the accelerometer.

[image]

Comment: Cool... The video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaZSJnWz6VY

Comment: Unbelievable...

Comment: Amazing. Beauty is in the little things.

Comment: How is this useful?

Comment: As far as I can tell, only the iPhone/iPod Music app has this feature.

Comment: I tried this on my 3GS and it did not work.  I suppose it uses the gyro.

Comment: With the recent iOS 6.1 update, this effect is also applied on the lock screen volume slider, but still not the multitasking tray slider.

Answer (score 28):

### [Do not disturb](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5463)

> You can use the Do Not Disturb setting while your iOS device is locked to silence calls, alerts, and notifications.

The setting is located at **Settings > Notifications > Do Not Disturb.**

Also very handy as it will silence a call but if the same person rings back within three minutes it wont silence it.

Comment: That cool.  How do you setup the time range?  I only see an on/off switch?

Comment: @AngryHacker Settings > Notifications > Do Not Disturb

Comment: hardly undocumented, though.

Answer (score 27):

**Uploading images** on Safari makes it easier to share images on websites that don't have apps.

Comment: And it saves your recent picks in a quick pick list

Answer (score 26):

Newly downloaded apps have a "new" label on the home screen.

[image: App Label New]

Comment: Mentioned in the keynote address. But still cool :)

Comment: Not an undocumented feature.

Comment: This is the least hidden feature.

Answer (score 26):

**The Settings icon no longer has**
*RAZOR BLADE EDGES!*

[image: Image of both the old and the new settings icons]

Comment: Is this really a *feature* or just a change?

Comment: That's a feature. Now the gear could actually be working, without the top spikes that are too narrow.

Comment: According to the initial question you should state "how this is useful". Is this something useful? ;-)

Answer (score 25):

## Opt Out of Advertising Tracking

Settings > General > About > Advertising allows you to turn off ad tracking. Details in the photo below.

[image]

Comment: yeah, retina sizes... woooooooooooooow there.

Comment: Wow, *that's* buried in an out-of-the-way place.

Answer (score 24):

### Dictionary in the Cloud

Now, iCloud syncs your weird words across all of your devices without giving suggestions.

Comment: Do you have to enable this? Is there a setting to turn it off or clear/edit the list of saved words?

Answer (score 24):

**New emojis** in the emojis keyboard!

[image]

Comment: Jack Wolfskin obviously paid more to Apple than Lacoste :-)

Answer (score 23):

Data Detectors finally separate a phone extension [416.555.5555 x101] and provide a button prompt to "DIAL [EXTENSION]" after the initial number is dialed.

[image: Screenshot]

Previously it would simply 'dial' all of the numbers lumped together [4165555555101].

Comment: How do you indicate that a number contains an extension?

Comment: I've only tested it a bit but a space then x### seems to work.  I suspect it will pick up a few other methods too.  But tried with 'ex' instead of x and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; how do you "dial" a space on the phone keypad?

Comment: It's not about dialing, it's about having a phone number in a contact, web page, or email where iOS' data detector turns it into a clickable link.

Answer (score 23):

### 15-second forward & rewind buttons in lock screen during podcast playback

Which replace previous and next track buttons in iOS 5 and prior.

[image]

Regular songs still have next & previous track buttons. It used to be too easy to accidentally push next or previous track while trying to pause a long podcast, causing you to completely lose your place. This change both solves that problem and offers a very handy quick-rewind option.

Answer (score 22):

## Add images and video to emails from within the Mail app

Tap in the body of an email you're writing and you'll get the standard "Select | Select All | Paste" options, but tap the right arrow and you get a new one: **Insert Photo or Video**.

Comment: This is documented on http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/

Answer (score 19):

## Landscape maps

Maps.app on iPhone now supports landscape orientation.

Comment: Is this undocumented?

Comment: I doubt it, but the question asks for "under-documented" features, not undocumented ones. Most of the answers to this question are documented somewhere.

Answer (score 19):

### Pull to refresh in Mail.app

Mail now has pull to refresh  (like Twitter, Facebook, etc.).  This is also now a standard control that third party developers can use.  So far I've only seen this new "native" pull to refresh in Lumatics City Maps but I'm sure it'll be everywhere soon enough.

Comment: And its got that nifty little rubber band globule thing, too!

Comment: About damn time!

Comment: I really dislike Apple's implementation though...

Answer (score 18):

**Signature by mail account**

You can now set a signature per mail account. Before it was a signature for all accounts set on iOS.

Set signatures in Settings > Mail, Contacts and Calendar > Signature.

Answer (score 17):

Browser history:

Hold down the back/forward button to see a list of pages you can select to go back to.

(This was previously only available on the iPad, but has now been added to the iPhone and iPod touch.)

Answer (score 16):

**iPad App Store screenshots can now be clicked** and seen in full screen "slideshow" mode.

They're definitely not Retina resolution, but still a much better indication what the app looks like on the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Acknowledging (swiping) a **Missed Call** through its **Notification** in a **Locked Screen** will now remove it from the Notifications.

Comment: Btput 'answering' you mean 'acknowledging the notificatioon', correct?

Comment: If by 'acknowledging the notification' you mean swiping on it, and, therefore, calling back, yes.

Comment: 'edited' for clarity

Answer (score 15):

App Store experience redesign. Most notably, when you install or update an application the App Store App no longer closes but instead show the download/installation progress inside the store (below the icon).

Comment: This is MUCH better!

Answer (score 15):

Email accounts in the mail app can now be sorted in the Mailbox view.

Answer (score 13):

### Panorama Panning Direction

Don't like the default left to right panning direction in Camera.app's new Panorama function? Just tap the arrow and it will change from right to left!

When the app quits, the direction defaults back to left to right.

Just happened to hit the arrow yesterday by accident and saw the change. A nice feature, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it is there, other than to help the dyslexic among us (and I am one of them, so no flames, please)!

Answer (score 11):

The clock app on iPad 3. I had no idea it was coming...

Comment: Well this was just mentioned in the long list of features during the update.

Comment: Yes, but for me it got buried under the noise about maps/youtube/siri/etc.

Answer (score 9):

A web inspector for mobile Safari.

Goto Settings > Safari > Advanced and turn on web inspector, then open Safari on your Mac and you can use the web inspector on the Mac to inspect the web page opened on mobile Safari.

Answer (score 8):

Auto-correct now considers your keyboard shortcuts when giving you suggestions and correcting your typing. In iOS 5, if you had a keyboard shortcut defined, you had to type it in exactly in order to get the substitution. iOS 6 now guesses that you meant to enter one of your shortcuts, and offers the substitution straight up even if you were going to misspell the shortcut.

Answer (score 7):

## Delete Messages in Gmail

Some email providers support archiving emails (most well known: Gmail). Now you have the option to archive or delete a message.

Tap-hold the delete button to access the menu options "Delete Message" and "Archieve Message".

**Update:** According to @Phong this does not work with Gmail.

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't work for Gmail. If turn off "Archive Mail" under account properties, then tapping-and-holding only gives you the option to delete. If you turn it on, then tapping-and-holding gives you both options, but both do the same thing (archiving). You would expect it to work with Gmail since All Mail now has a distinctive "Archive" icon, but Apple likely only tested this with iCloud Mail.

Comment: @Phong Oh wow, that's disappointing. :( I got this tip from [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5944961/top-10-secret-features-of-ios-6). I'll add this info about Gmail. Thanks for the update!

Comment: I know, I was so disappointed when I found out (I think I saw it on Lifehacker also) :(

Comment: With iOS 7, this feature finally works with Gmail!

Answer (score 7):

## Rotate maps

In the new maps app, use two fingers to rotate the map.  Now you can orient the map exactly in a way that makes sense.  It even remembers the rotation if you rotate your device.

And even better, if you activate the compass, and then move away from your position, it remembers the rotation (previously when you moved away, it rotated back to north being up, which was *very* annoying).

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to enter your password any longer when updating an app you've already bought and installed.

Comment: how does the update work then?

Comment: I hated having to do that...soo much better now!

Comment: @carbonr You press update, it starts updating. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 6):

**PRIVACY**

Now we have a better control over application that require personal data!

With the privacy field on "Settings", we can see which application have access to your contacts, your calendar, your photos, your bluetooth,  and disable this access directly from "Settings -> Privacy".

(By my point of view this is very important!)

Comment: I didn't understand. Which kind of control?

Comment: This is opinion, what feature(s) specifically has been added to support this?

Comment: @Mort The Privacy panel on Settings!

Comment: Screenshots or specific examples of how this is useful will prevent further downvoting...

Comment: @JoshNewman Done.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new French keyboard setup under Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboard: `Accented AZERTY`.

This layout adds an extra context-sensitive key between <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd>. It will switch between an apostrophe and various accents depending on the first letter to the left of the input cursor:

[image: Accented AZERTY] [image: Context-sensitive key]

Comment: Wow, great, thanks! I am intrigued by the “encrypted” mention on your mail, though. What trickery is this?

Comment: @MattiSG iOS supports S/MIME (since 5.0, I believe). If you have a certificate you can import it into your iPhone/iPad/iPod touch to sign and encrypt outgoing messages.

Answer (score 6):

Safari on iPad now lets you open up to 24 tabs, up from 8 previously. The iPhone is still limited to 8, sadly ;(

Also, the <kbd>+</kbd> button for opening a blank tab becomes disabled once you reach the limit on both iPhone and iPad, although you can still lose tabs inadvertently by opening links in new tabs after reaching the limit.

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 5, Apple added a "Store" button to the upper-left of the Music app. It used to drive me nuts because I'd tap it as I was backing out of a long stack of views (for example, traversing back from now playing, to artist's album list, to the artist list).

In iOS 6, a slight delay has been added to that button. If you back up through the stack in 6, the first tap on the Store button no longer activates it.

Comment: This is excellent, and undoubtedly the result of intense attention to how users interact with the app

Answer (score 4):

Opening a new tab in iPad's Safari now focuses the URL Bar instead of the Search bar.

Comment: Very annoying feature :-(

Comment: Still not sure why there are even two bars.  They changed it in Mountain Lion.

Comment: @asmeurer, it's so the OS can display an appropriate keyboard. It makes it easier to type a URL when that's what you want to do. Still, Apple could fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Reference Dictionaries for French, German, and Spanish (in addition to the one for Chinese mentioned in Apple's "new features" list).

These could be downloaded when I tapped the "define" option for a selected word in those languages.

Answer (score 3):

The animation in an app does not stop when double-pressing the home button. For example, go to the messages app, scroll in a long conversation and double-tap the home button.

Answer (score 3):

## Improved accessibility features

iOS 6 gains some really neat features concerning accessibility.
For example, there is the all new Guided Access feature which allows you to prohibit people from leaving a specific app or even from using certain interface areas. It can also disable sleeping the screen and motion controls (like rotation and shaking).

[image]

Also, Apple added the ability to adjust the speed with which you have to double- or triple- click the home button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you are viewing a location's details in Maps the 'distance' ticks up/down as you get closer/further, I really love this.

Answer (score 2):

[Apple's new iOS 6 Maps support automatic offline use for a wide area](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/10/05/apples-new-ios-6-maps-support-automatic-offline-use-for-a-wide-area)

> Vector maps in iOS 6 are so efficient that Apple can cache a very large surrounding area for offline browsing and GPS navigation under Airplane Mode or when traveling outside of data coverage.

Map data cache is available even after power cycling. Hybrid and 3D building model are cached.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to add an Internet link to your Reading List straight from Mail. You no longer have to open the link in Safari before saving it to your Reading List.

More globally, this is made possible by the OS-wide Reading List API, enabling any app to interact with the Reading List.

Answer (score 1):

Open in.... for documents is no longer limited to the last 10 suitable apps. That is, if one taps and holds a PDF mail attachment, for example, all the apps capable of opening the PDF are presented for selection (may need to swipe to second screen, but they are all there).

Answer (score 0):

### Delete own Shared Photostream comments

You can delete shared Photostream comments by tapping and holding on your own comment until the Copy | Delete options appear. The option to "Delete" only appears on comments you have made.

This can be very helpful if you happen to mistype, or if you say something you later wish you hadn't.

Answer (score -4):

Rearrange mailboxes. I receive email from about 8 different email addresses and now you can rearrange the order in which they appear.

From the Mailbox Screen, select Edit in top right hand corner of the panel. The three transparent grey lines that indicate moving/rearranging appear. Drag and drop accordingly.

Comment: This answer was already posted previously.