# How can I view the time of a text message in iOS 7?

Tags: messages, ios, sms

In iOS 7, I've noticed that some SMS/MMS messages have a date and time stamp displayed above the message.  Although this is useful, not all text's in the list receive such a date and time stamp.

Is there a way that I can view the date and time for ever text message?

Comment: Why do you ask a question when you at the same time already know the answer (not only in this thread) ?? - If you just want to share some new features, you can use this thread: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101382/what-are-some-hidden-or-undocumented-features-in-ios-7

Comment: First, this isn't a feature as much as it has seemed to be a loss of functionality.  (I believe iOS 6 use to just show this information without the need of a swipe gesture.) Also, it is considered good practice, as part of the StackExchange community, to post questions with their answers if you've found this information useful. I posted this question because I have found that when I find information that has helped me, usually there are many others who will find this beneficial as well.  People looking for this specific answer may not stumble upon the above linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is and, in fact, I stumbled upon this the other day.  Both my wife and I rejoiced!

To view the time of your texts, simply swipe your finger gently to the left.  While you hold down your finger, your texts will shift to the left, and time stamps will be revealed on the right.

Comment: I'll be honest.  I can't recall if iOS 6 behaved this way because I've been using iOS 7 beta for months.  However, as mentioned, my wife and I were both glad to find that there was a way to see when we had messaged each other.